# Big-$O$ notation and constant values

Tags: asymptotics

Function f(x) $n^3 2^n$  is:
a) $O(\ln n)$
b) $O(n^{3 + n})$
c) $O(2^n)$
d) $O (n^3)$
e) None of the above

Definition:

**$f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ if there are positive real constants $C$ and $x_0$ such that $f(x) \leq C g(x)$ for all values of $x \geq x_0$.**

Choice b) $O(n^{3 + n})$ seems correct, but how is constant C and $x_0$ values chosen. If constant $C$ was large , choice c) $O(2^n)$  could also satisfy $f(x) \leq C g(x)$.

Comment: @avs:  you changed the original option b, which was $n^{3+n},$ to $n^3+n$.  These are very different and b is no longer correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan edited back. I think now option $b)$ is right

Comment: b) is still incorrect: a polynomial is outgrown by an exponential.

Comment: Yes, option b is right, but you didn' t get the place in the text that was changed.

Comment: @RossMillikan, you are right, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

No, a polynomial function, $n^k$, is outgrown by the exponential $2^n$.  This can be seen by using, say, L'Hopital's rule to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  {x^k \over 2^x}.
$$

The best (i.e., smallest in the order of growth) big-$O$ estimate for $f(n) = n^k 2^n$ is that function itself.  All options, except for b) and e), that you are given, grow slower than that, hence can't serve as the upper bound.

However, the function $g(n) = n^n$ does outgrow both exponentials and polynomials, and is present in b).  Hence, that's the right option.  Yes, it serves as a very crude upper bound, but it is the only upper bound among the options you are given.

For practical guidance, see section "Properties" in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is not complete.  Formally, if $f \sim O(g)$, then
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = C \ne 0,$$
where $C < \infty$.
Option b) is certainly not correct.

Comment: The definition of big O in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and elsewhere I have seen it does not impose $\neq 0$.  That is reserved for $\Theta$.

Comment: If the constant $C = 0$, then we might say that $f \sim o(g)$ (little 'o' notation).

Comment: Yes, that is true, but it is not excluded from big O.  We have $n \in O(n^2)$ for example.  It is also true that $n \in o(n^2)$ and not true that $n \in \Theta(n^2)$

Comment: @RossMillikan, perhaps you could explain what is meant by $\Theta$?

Comment: @RossMillikan but in usual algorithm complexity, $n=o(n^2)\neq O(n^2)$

Comment: It is exactly what you are saying O is.  They are within a multiplicative constant of each other.  The family I have seen is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).

Comment: @RossMillikan I think $f=\Theta(g)$ if $\exists C_1,C_2:C_1g\le f\le C_2g$

Comment: I believe that is equivalent to your O definition with your $C$ somewhere in $[C_1,C_2]$

Answer (score 1):

Option c is not correct.  If you claim $n^32^n \in O(2^n)$ I will ask you to state what values $x_0$ and $C$ have.  Then I just have to find an $n \gt x_0$ where it fails, which means that $n^3 \gt C$.  Clearly I can choose $n$ large enough to do that.